# Getting SQL Server 2016 more processor time

Tags: sql-server

This is on a file vault for checking files in and out.

I have SQL Server 2016 express running on a Microsoft Server. The server exists almost exclusively to run the application that uses the SQL Server. The Windows server also serves files but that load is very low. It also serves as a license server for an application but that traffic is almost non existent.

I noticed that the most processor that SQL Server seems to use at any one time is 25%. Some operations can take a very long time to complete when managing files and rearranging files.

I know that SQL Server can be very complicated to manage and take a specific skill set. I don't want to and don't have the time to become a SL server expert.

Are there some basic things I can do to increase processor utilization in this case?

Answer (score 0):

> I have SQL Server 2016 express running on a Microsoft Server.
>
> I noticed that the most processor that SQL Server seems to use at any one time is 25%.

I'm not sure if this is a virtual or physical server and we don't know how many processors it has, thus 25% could be 4 cores or 25% could be 1 core. This will directly effect the usage of SQL Server Express Edition.

[From the Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016) for SQL Express limitations:

> Limited to lesser of 1 socket or 4 cores

Thus if you have a VM set to be wide (1 core per socket) the actual config of the VM is what's killing you. If it's a physical, you're at the mercy of the physical layout (which is generally 4 or more cores per socket).

There are other considerations which we'd need to do an analysis on the wait stats for the instance to see where it's mostly waiting. Additionally Express edition will shut down databases that are inactive after a certain period of time which can contribute to high waits for the application upon first or intermittent connections, this cannot be changed.

> Are there some basic things I can do to increase processor utilization in this case?

If it's a VM make it narrow (at least 4 cores/socket), that's all you can do from a hardware/config perspective at this point without looking and tuning the workload.

Comment: Hmmm... The current setup is a virtual server (ESXi). The physical machine that ESXi is on has two processors with 6 core each - Xeon(R) CPU X5670 @ 2.93GHz. I currently have the VM server set to 8 cores in the virtual machine set up. Looks like my setup can only use 4 cores max anyway. I'll change that set up to 4 cores. I do see there is SQL Server Profiler. I am guessing that I can check for wait times somehow there?

Comment: @Eric If you already see it using 4 cpus then it's hit the max. Some versions of ESXi automatically set hardware configurations based on number of vcpus given to a guest - just going by vcpus doesn't mean anything. The overall server wait stats are help in sys.dm_os_wait_stats but if you want to get into performance tuning I'd advise you to open up a new question on the DBA.SE site.